# How to install and configure Grub for booting (grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.)

Tags: grub

I want to make a custom booting. I've read I can use `grub-install`.
I made a partition where I want grub to be installed so that I can edit boot menu later.
`sudo grub-install /dev/sdb2` gives

```
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.
```

I've found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174206/warning-file-system-ext2-doesnt-support-embedding-but-my-system-isnt-emb the reason answers say you install to partition, not disk. Ok, `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` gives `Installation finished.`, but where am I supposed to find config menu? embedded area between MBR and 1st partition? how to mount that then? Or what can be done to have menu and config on the partition I selected for grub?

P.S. web search for `error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.` did not lead me to solve my issue too.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to mount the partition where grub files need to be and install grub to disk with option `--boot-directory` pointing to folder in that partition using Linux mount path.